# Using my laptop with 2 additional external monitors

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I got a ASUS Zenbook Pro (i7, 16gb memory, nvidia 960). I bought 2 Dell 27" monitors, connected one through hdmi and the other through an external usb-c to hdmi adapter.

It all works fine with those 2 monitors, the only thing is that I can't use the laptop built-in monitor as a third monitor.

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, your laptop's graphics card only supports 2 displays at once. So you can use both external monitors, or one of them and your laptop display.

The only advantage to this is that you can set your laptop to do nothing when the lid is closed and tuck it away somewhere if you connect a usb keyboard and mouse so it can seem like you're using a desktop computer.

The only way to get around this limitation is to buy [some sort of displaylink device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004D0QC0A) that converts usb to a video-out interface. This display however would have slight lag since it's limited to usb speed, and it would use a bit more cpu power to render it.